# Why was that question was declared off-topic?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I thought all questions about browser add-ons where on topic.

In that case, I’m failing to understand, why this question is not in the scope of this website :

> [Does Encrypted Media Extensions is theoritically putting an end to viewing videos where connection speed is too low for streaming?](https://superuser.com/q/1336815)

Comment: EME as a spec says nothing about connection speed. We chose off-topic but equally valid would be unclear what you are asking or opinion based.

Comment: @DavidPostill EME implies video must not be downloaded but accessed as streaming. In the title, I made clear the only way for me to watch videos is to download them. Is it rather because you don’t understand EME is about ?

Comment: Are you asking about the conspiracy that a new standard effectively means only high-speed users will ever be able to view video content?

Comment: @random no I Simply think they didn’t made thoughts for peoples who cannot afford to live in top downtowns like them, not that they wanted to prevent from viewing videos legally. And I’m not even sure this prevent downloading videos that can be decrypted since I can get the keys from the keyserver, that’s why I’m asking : on wether this is still possible in theory or not, if not how this can be still acheived ?

Comment: On my side my country has a plan to provide very high speed connection to the whole territory, but Macron asked it want it completed 7 years sooner, this will achevied by greatly lowering the low speed level : the speed at which connection speed isn’t considered low bandwith. That’s how I won’t have access to fiber since now I’m considered to be on high speed connection (less than 1M/s). This was confirmed by ISP in my place.

Comment: @random : not to mention https://www.wired.com/2016/06/bug-chrome-makes-easy-pirate-movies/ though exploit details aren’t public. Though in my case, I wonder if it‘s possible to decrypt from a file.

Comment: My decision to issue a close vote had nothing to do with what region of the world you live it.  Your question was not clear.  I think I even said that in a comment.

Comment: @Ramhound it can’t be clearer : I don’t live in a place where video streaming is possible. Does Encrypted Media Extensions now fully prevent downloading a video for viewing it from locally ? Or is there way to play a downloaded video with the keys ? What’s unclear ?

Comment: `Encrypted Media Extensions` is just a standard.  A standard isn't going to standardize, the process of preventing downloading a video, and creating a local file.  Other users have expressed the reasons it was unclear.  I am not going to choose to repeat those reasons.

Comment: @Ramhound if there’s a way to implement the standard correctly which would still allow to download videos illegally, then it’s an answer.

Comment: Have you actually encountered an implementation of the standard that does that though?  It’s not like we are aware of every implementation of the standard.  You certainly didn’t ask that question.  You made a point of saying the question wasn’t about downloading files illegally though.  You linked to a non-English YouTube video.

Comment: @Ramhound I didn’t encountered an implementation doing it, but that doesn’t means building one that does is impossible. I rather do not care if the way to access the content I paid for is legal or not since I cannot access it by streaming : the Youtube video explains my situation, in the Video link I explained that peoples should enable automatic subtitling for translation.

Comment: @user2284570 The linked video does not have **English** subtitles.  Questions here at SuperUser are expected to be in English.

Answer (score 5):

Without the YouTube video your question is unclear.

> But does EME makes a requrierment to ᴡatch concerned protected videos this way

What is "this way"? Linking "this way" to a YouTube video is, to me at least, the worst and laziest thing you could have done. You should use real words to describe your problem *clearly*. Is EME actually important here? I doubt you would only just have gotten this problem because of EME, and without video downloader programs you would have this problem anyway.

How you phrase the question is important. You start out with a solution (that doesn't work), move into a question that is only tangentially related to your actual problem (a site making it difficult for you to download videos), and then moves on to "I don't want to pirate/redistribute videos".

You've only really **hinted** what your problem is in your question, and then you've asked it in an order that is nonsensical and full of unqualified assumption about what we know about your problem.

If you want help then tell us what your actual problem is as clearly and succinctly as you can. Then tell us what you tried so far, what used to work and why it no longer works.

At a quick glance I cannot tell if the video is an actual example of what you get or simply a mock up or even if the quickly passing subtitles (which are in a foreign language) are important. In short it does not help people *here* without having to spend time working out what the video is telling them. Many people watch films or listen to music while using their computers and opening "yet another" video or having more noise can be aggravating and turn them off of answering your question or even reading it in the first place.

Perhaps a better question would be

> what is it about EME that makes it difficult to download a video for offline use?

But that is actually very broad and implementation specific and potentially still off topic for being vague and broad. It depends a lot on how the site is coded and media is transferred and chances are you would need downloader for every site as there are a lot of ways it could be implemented, particularly where DRM is concerned.

Or, more simply, one you could ask your video site of choice (but not us as it would be off topic here)

> Do you have a program that would allow me to watch your videos offline?

Amazon (and other suppliers) often have Android or iOS apps which support downloading for offline use.